# Getting data from firebase not works

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I init my web app with firebase, then I add new data into database: {'title': 'hello world!'}. Then I try to get this data: `database.ref().child('title')` and  I got strange object:
[image]

My code:

```
export class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "&&&&&&&dbBJY_ie3CbXtnL6M6QBEL2JqWI",
            authDomain: "&&&&&&&.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "&&&&&test-61197.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "test-&&&&.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "7&&&1193299"
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        // Get a reference to the database service
        var database = firebase.database();

        console.log(database.ref().child('title'));

    }

    login() {
        console.log('login');
        // Log the user in via Twitter

    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Touchable style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={ this.login }>
              <Text style={styles.loginBtnText}>login</Text>
          </Touchable>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

How to get my data?
Firebase version: 3.4.0

Comment: Can you show us your code? My guess is that you have to call `.val()` on that object.

Comment: Yes, it's my code: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1mxc9zsg/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase queries are asynchronous. Hence, you need to register a callback so that Firebase can inform you when the results are ready.

Try this:

```
database.ref().child('title').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

You may read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways of retrieving data in Firebase. First is to wait for an event to happen on your RTDB using a listener:

```
 var myTitleRef =  database.ref('title');
  myTitleRef.on("value",function(snapshot){
     //snapshot contains the data you're looking for  
     HandleTitle(snapshot);
  });
```

The other way is to call a REST GET on your data, in this case you need the entire url of the DB and add ".json" at the end. In this example I'll use jQuery:

```
var myurl = pathToYourDatabase + 'title.json';
$.ajax({
            url: myurl,

            jsonp: "callback",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function( response ) {
                //Response contains data
                DoSomethingWithTitle(response);
            }
        });
```

For more information, you should read the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Answer (score 0):

Your **reference is empty** and the **database is not being called** .

**Example :**

The right way :

```
var data = database().ref('/your root destination').child('title');
```

You were missing the `()` after database .

**UPDATE : 
Your code and the code I've demonstrated above is to actually create a database entry .**

**Now to get the data from this entry  :**

```
data.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var objectData = snapshot.val();

});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The argument for the `.ref` method is optional. When it's not specified, a ref to the root will be returned. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference

Comment: correct if we're assuming the child 'title' is a direct descendant of the root ...

Comment: Right, that's true. I misunderstood your answer as claiming that `.ref()` doesn't work.

Comment: @KpTheConstructor and yihangho, I totally understand both your answers, but being new to nodeJs I'm can't understand where to put it. For Eg. All my nodeJs code that gives me feed back start with - "exports.myNotiFunc = functions.database.ref('/messages/{MsgId}')
    .onWrite(event => {..." All works perfectly from my Java program. I'm trying to practice the NodeJs too. So how may I put this in my NodeJs to get that data once?